# Change color of <li> in <ul>

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have code with some `<li>` in `<ul>`

Here is it

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="color:black;">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
</ul>
```

I need to change color of `<li>` to black

I try to do it like this `style="color:black;"`

This is ASP.NET code

Here is genereted code

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li style="color:#000000;"><a href="/Account/Register" id="registerLink">Register</a></li>
    <li style="color:#000000;"><a href="/Account/Login" id="loginLink">Log in</a></li>
</ul>
```

But color didn't changed.

How I can change it?

Comment: Is that ASP? Show the rendered HTML please. Looks like these will generate `a` tags, so you need to apply the style to the `a` or use something like `.nav a { color: black; }`

Comment: Yes, will update post now@MichaelCoker

Comment: You wanna try htmlAttributes: new {@style='color:black'} in your >@Html.ActionLink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add class inside 'htmlAttributes' in ActionLink.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink", @class = "aclass" })
```

And inside your css:

```
/* Class of 'a' element
.aclass {
      color: black;
      ......
}
```

This should work.

EDIT:
You must use '@', because class is a keyword in C#. 
Link to the MSDN documentation:

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124(v=vs.108).aspx)

Comment: Try with '@class = "aclass"' insted of 'class = "aclass"'. Add a '@' before class attr. (I have edited my answer) @s.e.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li style="color:black;">@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
    <li style="color:black;">@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
</ul>
```

However, since it looks like you are rendering an anchor-tag inside the `<li>`, they might not be black. Since you can't add the style-attribute to the anchor tags, you will have to add this CSS:

```
ul.navbar-nav a {
    color: #000;
}
```